# Ruby require and self.require

Tags: ruby, require, program-entry-point, self

I ruby 1.8.7, Why I can use require in main, but can't use self.require?

```
require('date') # ok
self.require('date') 
NoMethodError: private method `require' called for main:Object
from (irb):22
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/date.rb:437
```

Well known that main is Object class:
    irb(main):045:0> self
    => main

```
irb(main):043:0> self.class
=> Object
```

But I discovered that it have Kernel mixin:

```
irb(main):042:0> self.class.included_modules
=> [Kernel]
```

Moreover, I found that require is private method of self:

```
irb(main):037:0> self.private_methods
=> [... "require", ...]
```

Same way, I can't use self.attr_accessor:

```
irb(main):051:0> class X
irb(main):052:1> self.attr_accessor(:ssss)
irb(main):053:1> end
NoMethodError: private method `attr_accessor' called for X:Class
from (irb):52
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/date.rb:437
```

How does it happend? Can anybody clarify that questions?

Comment: Moreover, I can't use self.attr_accessor in class definition:

Comment: `self.send(:require, 'date')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the following simple example:

```
class Person
  def initialize(age)
    @age = age
  end

  def compare_to(other)
    # we're calling a protected method on the other instance of the current class
    age <=> other.age
  end

  # it will not work if we use 'private' here
  protected

  def age
    @age
  end
end
```

In ruby we have implicit and explicit methods receiver, check the next code snippet:

```
class Foo
  def a; end

  # call 'a' with explicit 'self' as receiver
  def b; self.a; end

  # call 'a' with implicit 'self' as receiver
  def c; a; end
end
```

Basically in ruby if a method is `private` it can be called only on `implicit` receiver (without `self` keyword). In your example `require` is a `private` method defined the `Kernel` module and it can be called only on the `implicit` subject.

Answer (score 2):

`require` is a private method. So you can't call it just as

```
Object.require 'date'
```

But you can call it with ruby's eval/send methods:

```
Object.send(:require, 'date')
# or
self.send(:require', 'date')
```

What is actually very simillar to

```
require 'date'
```

For example [pry console](https://github.com/pry/pry) will interpret it as

```
instance_exec do
  require 'date'
end
```

I believe that Ruby interpreter will do almost the same. It will pass any top level commands as an `instance_exec` block to `Object`, which can call any private method.

Answer (score 0):

Private methods can only be called with an implicit receiver. This means `require` will work, but `self.require` won't.

Protected method can be called on `self`, and public methods can be called explicitly on any object.

Those are the only restrictions. Yes, you can use private methods in subclasses, and `send` will bypass any and all access controls.

Comment: private setters *can* be called as `self.attr = :foo`, in fact, they *have* to be called that way, because `attar = :foo` is a local variable assignment.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, you're right. Does this work with any method that ends in `=`, or just the setters defined by `attr_writer` and `attr_accessor`? Can you provide a link to the sources which implement this behavior?

Comment: There is absolutely nothing special about `attr_writer`. In fact, it's really just `class Module; def attr_writer(*attrs) attrs.each do |attr| define_method(:"#{atttr}=") do |val| instance_variable_set(:"@#{attr}", val) end end end end`. So, yes, this works for any method that ends with `=`, because otherwise you would never be able to call it. [Here's the relevant spec.](https://GitHub.Com/RubySpec/RubySpec/blob/master/language/send_spec.rb#L202-216).